# touch-events not working in latest chromium version

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium, touch-event

Using electron JS for one of our desktop apps, now we are upgrading electron version. When we upgrade electron version we noticed that touch functionality has stopped working.

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("--touch-events");
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("--enable-touch-events");
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("touch-events", "true");
```

When started researching came to know from chrome 78 they removed touch-events could someone help what is the event which enables the touch events in this case?

Tried with

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch("top-chrome-touch-ui", "true");
```

but no luck.